# How can I pass a double from a ComboBox into a math operation?

Tags: vb.net

I have this code in my form:

```
Private Sub Calculate()
    Dim Len, Wid, Height, Roll As Double
    Dim Ans, fans As Double

    Len = Convert.ToDouble(ComboBox1.Text)
    Wid = Convert.ToDouble(ComboBox2.Text)
    Height = Convert.ToDouble(ComboBox3.Text)
    Roll = Convert.ToDouble(ComboBox4.Text)

    Ans = Wid * Height * 2 + Len * Height * 2
    fans = Ans / Roll

    MessageBox.Show(Ans)
    MessageBox.Show(Roll)
    MessageBox.Show(fans)
End Sub
```

Whenever I try to add a double to `ComboBox4` (Roll Coverage) it says:

> Input string was not in the correct format

`ComboBox4` is populated with values ranging from `40` to `50` with increments of `0.5`. When I use a whole number the program runs, but when I use a double like `41.5` it bombs out.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe due to language settings it should be 41,5 - did you try this decimal separator?

Comment: It doesn't like something about the string. Either extra spaces or unicode characters, or a different culture expecting a `,` instead of `.` or something like that. Maybe if the `"` quotes are part of the text.

Comment: Also: I suggest getting that down to one MessageBox: `MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Ans: {1}{0}Roll: {2}{0}fans: {3}", vbTab, Ans, Roll, fans))`

Comment: @DávidLaczkó the ',' separator worked, thank you so much!

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I just added the message boxes for testing, I will be printing the final answer to a textbox, thank you for the suggestion though

Comment: OK, I added it as an answer, so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

The decimal separator is dependent of language settings, so, as per our comments, the solution is to use a comma. Just to document the solution for future readers.

Comment: The other option is `Double.Parse()` with an explicit culture, ie: `Double.Parse(Textbox4.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`.